# Why OpenMP-based Jacobi Stencil program is slower than sequential version

Tags: c++, openmp

Can someone tell me why the OpenMP-based Jacobi iteration is so slower than the sequential version?

```
ITERATION = 100;
DIM = 4000;

// sequential version takes only ~5 seconds
for(size_t i=0; i<ITERATION; ++i) {
  for(size_t y=1; y<(DIM-1); ++y) {
    for(int x=(y*DIM)+1; x<(y*DIM) + DIM-1; ++x) {                                                                                              
      dest[x]=(src[x-DIM]+src[x+DIM]+src[x]+src[x-1]+src[x+1])*0.2;
    }   
  }   
  std::swap(dest, src);
}

// openmp version takes 7s on 4 cores
for(size_t i=0; i<ITERATION; ++i) {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(size_t y=1; y<(DIM-1); ++y) {
    for(int x=(y*DIM)+1; x<(y*DIM) + DIM-1; ++x) {
      dest[x]=(src[x-DIM]+src[x+DIM]+src[x]+src[x-1]+src[x+1])*0.2;
    }
  }
  std::swap(dest, src);
}
```

I use four threads and compile the program with O2 flag.

Comment: How are you dealing with optimization?  -O3?

Comment: How many threads do you expect this code to create ?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue...